# Need a "localStorage" replacement for Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I have code that uses localStorage to save a value on one page which I use on another. The code works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE. (after the setting if the item, it is null when localStorage.getItem is attempted.) Could someone please tell me what I can do instead for this behavior to work on Firefox and IE? I'm assuming that localStorage is the culprit. Thank you! Here is the code (Note: our website uses no database):

```
//Called when a list item is clicked
function saveData(selected) {
   var selectedItem = {
     Item: selected
   };
   //converts to JSON string the Object
   selectedItem = JSON.stringify(selectedItem);
   //creates a base-64 encoded ASCII string
   selectedItem = btoa(selectedItem);
   //save the encoded accout to web storage
   localStorage.setItem('_selectedItem', selectedItem);
}

//Colors the border of the div that has the selected item as an id.
function colorBorder() {
     var selectedItem = localStorage.getItem('_selectedItem');
     if (!selectedItem) return false;
     localStorage.removeItem('_selectedItem');
     //decodes a string data encoded using base-64
     selectedItem = atob(selectedItem);
     //parses to Object the JSON string
     selectedItem = JSON.parse(selectedItem);
     //Get the element that goes with the one selected in the list
      var selectedDiv = document.getElementById(selectedItem.Item);
      selectedDiv.style.borderColor = "red";
     return true;
}
```

Comment: What's not working? localStorage is supported in all browsers including IE. Please post a demo to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I test localStorage in IE and it works well. I think the issue might be related with other part of code. Have you used F12 dev tools to check if there's any error in console and the error in which line of code? Please provide the detailed error message so that we can do more research.

Comment: THANK YOU for your comments. There are no errors; however, when I get my item from localStorage, it is null. 

UPDATE: I was able to get it to work on Firefox using cookies, but it still doesn't work in the Edge browser. 

Could you please tell me how I submit the entire program here? Is there a place to attach files or do I cut and paste everything into the message body with titles of the files above each section of code? Thank you.

Comment: No, you don't need to post the entire program, you just need to provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**. Can you set localStorage in IE? Have you added breakpoints to debug the code line by line in IE to see what's going wrong? Besides, how do you define the `btoa()` and `atob()` function?

Comment: It SEEMS to be getting set (selectedItem is not null on the last line of saveData(), but when the item is fetched in the first line of colorBorder(), selectedItem is null after that line executes. Of course, in Chrome, selectedItem is not null and everything works fine.

btoa() encodes a string in base-64 while atob() decodes a base-64 encoded string. I found that code online; I did not write the functions. I figured that they are required with localStorage.

Comment: I think the localStorage is not set in IE when you run the code. Which version of IE are you using? LocalStorage doesn't work at all in IE versions prior to 8. Besides, are you testing your code on a local HTML file using `file:///` protocol? It won't work in IE. You need to use `http://` or `https://` protocols to host your file to test the code.

Comment: Omg! That was it!!! Yu, you are a genius! Thank you!! I am so embarrassed. If I run my program on a web server, it works on all the browsers that I was having an issue with!!! (I have moved from using local storage to cookies, but still couldn't get it to work with all browsers. I am new to web development and didn't even consider the problem being that I was testing locally.) THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer JavaScript:

// This is on page1.html

```
   var myData = {
      'key1' : 'value1',
      'key2' : 'value2'
      };
      
       var storedData = [ MyData ];

       localStorage.setItem( 'objectToPass', storeData );

     Javascript on page2.html

     // Get the variable
      var myData = localStorage['objectToPass'];
      localStorage.removeItem( 'objectToPass' ); // Clear the localStorage
      var firstData = myData[0];
     alert('firstData: ' + firstData);
```

I think that will work (not tested)

D

Comment: Thank you, Dave, but this is the code that I originally used. It works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox or IE/Edge. I'm trying to find a replacement for the usage of localStorage that Firefox and IE will accept.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `localStorage` is not set in IE when you run the code.

`LocalStorage` doesn't work at all in IE versions prior to 8. Besides, are you testing your code on a local HTML file using `file:///` protocol? It won't work in IE. You need to use `http://` or `https://` protocols to host your file to test the code.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a the ATTR and set/unset it.  that way you dont have F with local storage.
I currently am using attr("data-val") to store the drop down value from an HTML drop down element.  Since there is no way to get the last drop down value I can use local storage (which I dont like cause I cant see it in the DOM), or I can use attr... and store the value that way.

Comment: But I need to access the selected html element from another web page. How would I do that, please?

Comment: Had the same issue awhile back The way I solved it was I created a hidden form field and using the name of the field, I then passed that to PHP.  I did mine with a button, but you can also use any event, just call it when you need to.  Over in the PHP file do a session start then get for your form value with $POST reassign to new var and then using session you can then pass that variable to another page.

 Here is my code:

Comment: HTML side:
        <form style="display:inline-block" action="bat/buttonStorage.php" 
            method="post"><button class="s_btn3" type="submit" name="Subject" 
             value="Concealed Carry Class">Sign Up</button> 
             <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Concealed Carry Class" />
         </form>

Comment: And on the PHP side:
       <?php
            session_start(); 
             if (isset($_POST['Subject'])) {
             $newSubject = $_POST['Subject'];
             $_SESSION['formvar'] = $newSubject;
          }
   
        header("Location: http://your url/page your passing to.html");
      ?>

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with PHP. I think it's time I GET familiar with it! I'm going into 3 Schools to understand the syntax of it.